# How to embed android emulator inside Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I know that an embedded emulator has been introduced in Android Studio 4.1+. I am not able to see options to enable it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The changelog says that you need to enable it manually. Follow these steps:

#### Steps

1. Open Android Studio and goto Preference / Settings

[image: Open Android Studio and goto Preference]

2. Expand the Tools tab and goto emulator
3. Check 'Launch in a tool window'

[image: Expand the Tools tab and goto emulator then check 'Launch in a tool window']

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the previous, if you dont't see the emulator tab in IDE:
I found that adding a "<module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/android/..." line in Project directory, file .idea/modules.xml the tab appears:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
    <component name="ProjectModuleManager">
        <modules>
            <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/renal_calc_flutter.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/renal_calc_flutter.iml" />
            <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/android/renal_calc_flutter_android.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/android/renal_calc_flutter_android.iml" />
        </modules>
     </component>
 </project>
```